# How to select only rows containing specific values with multiple data frame in for loop?

Tags: pandas, for-loop

I'm new to python, I have a multiple data frame and select data frame based one columns which contains value xxx.

below is my code

```
MasterFiles = [Master_Jun22, Master_May22, Master_Apr22, Master_Mar22, Master_Feb22, Master_Jan22,
          Master_Dec21, Master_Nov21, Master_Oct21, Master_Sep21, Master_Aug21, Master_Jul21,
          Master_Jun21, Master_May21, Master_Apr21]
ColumName = ['product_category']

for d in MasterFiles:
    for c in ColumName:
        d = d.loc[d[c]=='XXX']
```

it is not working please help on this.

Comment: What is not working, is this code giving error? or you are not getting expected output

Comment: not getting expected output, the datraframe remains same, actually it should have shown rows where where column product_category contains value xxx

Comment: Where are you saving the filtered row, you just overwrite them in the variable d

Comment: This is working but I need different data frame, currently this is combining into one data frame.

Answer (score 0):

You need to gather the output and append it to a new Dataframe:

```
MasterFiles = [Master_Jun22, Master_May22, Master_Apr22, Master_Mar22, Master_Feb22, Master_Jan22,
          Master_Dec21, Master_Nov21, Master_Oct21, Master_Sep21, Master_Aug21, Master_Jul21,
          Master_Jun21, Master_May21, Master_Apr21]
ColumName = ['product_category']

res_df = pandas.Dataframe(columns=ColumName)

for d in MasterFiles:
    for c in ColumName:
        res_df.append[d.loc[d[c]=='XXX']]

# the results
res_df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question correctly. So, please let me rephrase your question here.

You have 3 tasks,

- first is to loop through each pandas data frame,
- second is to loop through each column in your `ColumName` list, and
- third is to return the data frame rows that consists of value `Surabhi - DCL - Unsecured` based on the column name in the `columnName` list.

If I am interpreting this correctly. This is how I would work on your issue.

```py
MasterFiles = [Master_Jun22, Master_May22, Master_Apr22, Master_Mar22, Master_Feb22, Master_Jan22,
              Master_Dec21, Master_Nov21, Master_Oct21, Master_Sep21, Master_Aug21, Master_Jul21,
              Master_Jun21, Master_May21, Master_Apr21]
ColumName = ['product_category']

## list to store filter data frame by rows
df_temp = []

for d in MasterFiles:
    for c in ColumName:
        df_temp.append(d.loc[d[c] == 'Surabhi - DCL - Unsecured'])

## Assuming row wise concatenation
## i.e., using same column names to join data
df = pd.concat(df_temp, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
## df is the data frame you need
```